# How to find the max value in queue?

Tags: queue, max, system-verilog

I have an unsorted sorted queue (undefined size).

```
bit [31:0] addr_q [$]
```

How can I find its maximum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemVerilog has a number array querying methods described in **7.12.1 Array locator methods** of the [1800-2012 LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). A queue is one kind of unpacked array. Use

```
max_addr = addr_q.max();
```